# public struct in managed c++ dll cannot be seen from c#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a c# application. It references a c++-cli dll. In the namespace of the c++ dll a public struct is declared:

```
namespace Wrapper {

  public struct maxs
  {
     public:
      char Name[255];
      int num;
  };
etc
```

There is a function in the c++ dll which returns a pointer to a pointer to the struct.

```
Wrapper::Maxs** Wrapper::Class1::CallMax();
```

The C# application references the c++ dll and declares an instance of the struct (unsafe code)

```
 Wrapper.Class1 oMax = new Wrapper.Class1()
 Wrapper.Maxs** maxs; 
 maxs= oMax.CallMax();
 int num = oMax.m_num;
```

Then I try to access the fields of maxs like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
 {
    name = maxs[i]->name;
  }
```

However, that 'name' field is not visible in the c# intellisense and doesn't compile.
Interestingly I went to see the definition of the struct in the c++ metadata and the struct is blank..

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespaceWrapper
{
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [NativeCppClass]
    [UnsafeValueType]
    public struct Maxs
    {
    }
}
```

Is that normal?
So the question is: Why can c# not see the fields of the public struct Maxs? And why is the metadata info show a blank struct?
thanks.

Comment: Because it is not a managed struct.  You'll need to declare it as `public value struct` instead.

Comment: Thank you Hans! That got the job done and I learned something new.

Comment: @HansPassant: would you mind making that an answer, so the author can accept it..? I know that's pretty trivial, but this thread will hang otherwise. It's rather not eligible for being closed..

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct answer AFAIK:

*Because it is not a managed struct. You'll need to declare it as public value struct instead. – Hans Passant Mar 24 at 2:33*